# Why does MassTransit.Serialization.SystemTextJsonMessageSerializer 8.0.3 thrown an exception when configuring the bus in .NET 4.6.2 + ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, json.net, masstransit

We have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 ASP .NET MVC application that configures MassTransit.RabbitMQ 8.0.3 in the Startup class

The code is below

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer(); //Also tried UseNewtonsoftRawJsonSerializer and without

    cfg.Host(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"], "/", h =>
    {
        h.Username(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQUsername"]);
        h.Password(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQPassword"]);
    });

});
```

This is the exception

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'MassTransit.Serialization.SystemTextJsonMessageSerializer' threw an exception.
  Source=MassTransit
  StackTrace:
   at MassTransit.Configuration.SystemTextJsonMessageSerializerFactory.get_ContentType()
   at MassTransit.Configuration.SerializationConfiguration.AddSerializer(ISerializerFactory factory, Boolean isSerializer)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.SerializationConfiguration.AddSystemTextJson()
   at MassTransit.Configuration.EndpointConfiguration..ctor(ITopologyConfiguration topology)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Configuration.RabbitMqBusConfiguration..ctor(IRabbitMqTopologyConfiguration topologyConfiguration)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqBusFactory.Create(Action`1 configure)
   at Startup.ConfigureMassTransit(IUnityContainer unityContainer) in C:\p\Startup.cs:line 79
   at Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in C:\p\Startup.cs:line 59

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.DefaultJavaScriptEncoder' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 3:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Inner Exception 4:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image]

What I've tried

1. I read the [Serialization](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html#version-8) section of the MassTransit 8 upgrade guide. I added `UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer`. Same error.
2. I had a look at [Microsoft's Migration guide from NewtonSoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0). Our web app includes both System.Text.Json and NewtonSoft.Json. I tried uninstall System.Text.Json but Masstransit requires that. We use NewtonSoft.Json in a lot of places in our code.
3. I found some [assembly redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in the .config files. I removed those but I still get the  error.
4. Checked that System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (6.0) is installed (as a nuget package)

Questions

1. Why am I getting this error and how to I fix it?

Other details

1. One of the errors mentions "DefaultJavaScriptEncoder" and another mentions "SystemTextJsonMessageSerializer".
2. The Webapp uses Unity 5.6.0 (and Unity.Abstractions 3.2.0, Unity.Container 5.6.0, Unity.MVC 5.0.12, Unity.WebAPI 5.3.0)
3. Using MassTransit 7.1.8 we do not have these problems.

---

**Update 1**

Not adding this as an answer because it's specific to my system.

I managed to fix this by *adjusting* / *fiddling* with the dependenyAssembly / bindingRedirect in the web.config file.

I remove `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` dependencyAssembly / bindingRedirect.

I added these dependencyAssembly / bindingRedirect (which I got from the exception message: change dependencyAssembly, run program, get exception, repeat)

1. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
2. System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
3. Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces
4. System.Threading.Channels

   ```
   <!--<dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>-->
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.18.0" newVersion="3.1.18.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Channels" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```